# Only allow file download to logged in users

Tags: php, authentication, joomla, download, joomla2.5

Is there a way, and if so, how, to allow only logged in users to download a file using Joomla and PHP?

Here is the situation:

When users are logged in, they can click the product's download link to be brought to a download page. They click download, and are able to download the file. However, these users may be beta testers, or the file may be sensitive, so I need to, somehow, hide the direct link to the file. Be it a PHP file or something that checks if the user is logged in (I'm already familiar on how to do that) and send the file to them. (Rather than a link to a .zip file for instance, a link to a .php page that will push the file to them)

Answer (score 0):

Link to a PHP file in which you check if the user is logged in, and then you can initiate the download using the correct headers:

```
<?php
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= filename.ext");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
```

and then pass the file's contents through using [fpassthru()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php)

Comment: This is pretty much what I thought of as soon as I posted this

Comment: I would not link to an external/custom PHP file. Stick to methods that the Joomla CMS uses